# Prove that $a_n=(-1)^n$ does not converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I've managed to come up with a proof to this problem but I don't know if it's right.

> Prove that the sequence $a_n=(-1)^n$ does not converge.

Suppose the opposite, that

$(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists n(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N})$ such that $\forall n(\epsilon) > N$ we have:

$|(-1)^n-a|<\epsilon$.

Set $\epsilon=1$, then

$|(-1)^n-a|<1$

Note that for $n$-even we have:

$|(-1)^n-a|=|1-a|<1\\
\Leftrightarrow -1<1-a<1\\
\Leftrightarrow -2<-a<0\\
\Rightarrow -a\in(-2,0)
$

And for $n$-odd we have:

$|(-1)^n-a|=|-1-a|<1\\
\Leftrightarrow -1<-1-a<1\\
\Leftrightarrow 0<-a<2\\
\Rightarrow -a\in(0,2)
$

So, $-a\in(-2,0)\cap(0,2)\Rightarrow -a\in \emptyset$. We have concluded that the limit $a$ does not exist therefore the sequence $a_n=(-1)^n$ does not converge.

Comment: You can use a way simpler argument: the subsequences for odd/even $n$ converge to two different values - a necessary condition for a sequence to converge against some value is that all subsequences converge against that same value. So by the contrapositive of that statement your sequence can't converge. Alternatively you could argue that it's not a Cauchy-sequence.

Comment: For any small epsilon, there is no such $N$ so that $(-1)^n$ is within epsilon *of both $1$ and $-1$*, for all $n\gt N$; I can never put my foot down and claim we are always arbitrarily close.

Comment: One can also use $\varlimsup a_n=1\neq\varliminf a_n=-1$ which is the same argument than SV-97 but with other tools.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your proof by contradiction is correct. You assume that the limit $a$ exists and reach a contradiction that $-a\in\emptyset$.

Alternatively, you can simply observe that for *all* $n$:
$$
|a_{2n}-a_{2n+1}|=2
$$
So the sequence cannot be Cauchy and thus is not convergent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following proposition, a sequence $(u_n)$ converges only and only if : $(u_{2n})$ and $(u_{2n+1})$ converge such that $l=l'$ or simply to an unique limit.

Here $u_n =(-1)^n$ so $u_{2n}=1$ and $u_{2n+1} = -1$.

But :
$$u_n \longrightarrow 1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ \ u_{2n+1} \longrightarrow -1$$
Clearly $-1\neq 1$ which means the sequence diverges.